# Keras: Understanding result of test_on_batch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am using keras test_on_batch to predict mean square loss for my model. Here, I can either pass only train dataset as

`model.test_on_batch(data.reshape(1, -1))`

or

both train and test dataset as

`model.test_on_batch(data.reshape(1, -1), np.array([target]))`

The detail of test_on_batch is also given in its documentation as https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#testonbatch-method

Here, I am passing only one dataset at a time to get loss result. But both of the above are producing diferent loss result and I am unable to identify why ?

Can somebody point me out the reason ?

Comment: is `energy_level` your target?

Comment: yes let me edit it